# Collection of collection's references(may be of ArrayList or any other ) and want to use those references to create collections

Tags: java, list, collections

I have Collection of collection's references(may be of ArrayList or any other ) and I want to use those references and create collections.i.e

```
ArrayList courseTitle;   //the collection references   
ArrayList<Courses> courses=new ArrayList<Course>(); 
//an arraylist to store those references
```

now i want to use these references and create collections with them.i.e
like if i have a reference 'Maths' or 'Science' in course....then i want to create collection 
with name 'Maths' or 'MathsList'.I am confused how to implement it.need help!!

Answer (score 0):

Create new class which has the different attributes like courses like title, author etc.,

Implement an ArrayList for the specific type of class that is created.

Eg.

```
Class CourseDetails{
      public String courseTitle;
      public String author;
       //getters and setters ....

}
```

And create an arraylist as below in your class where you are implementing the functionality.

```
ArrayList<CourseDetails> arrayList = new ArrayList<CourseDetails>();
```

Hope this helps to some extent!

Comment: Actually the thing is that i have different Courses and for each course their are then different books,instructors.So initially i should have collection of courses,then the collection of books & instructors for each course.So i want to know the way we can create collection for each courses by using the courseTitles in my course collection and then using those collection to store further book & intructors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *Collection of collection's*, you should think of designing with classes.

As per your query and comment you want the structure as follows,

*Course* object

```
public class Course {
    String courseTitle;
    List<Book> books;
    List<Instructor> instructors;
}
```

*Book* class included in Course

```
public class Book {
    String name;
    String author;
}
```

*Instructor* class included in Course

```
public class Instructor {
    String name;
    String age;
    String experience;
}
```

Now you can create courses like maths or science like below

```
List<Course> maths =  new ArrayList<Course>
List<Course> science =  new ArrayList<Course>
```

Comment: what if i want to add a new user defined course....i mean taking a new course input from user & then creating courses like : List<Course> 'user defined'=new ArrayList<Course>();

Comment: What will be the user inputs?

Comment: thats why i took a collection of "collection's references" first,to which i can add the user input string as collection reference variables and then afterwords assign Collection to it(with new operator).

Comment: I still didnt get. What is the user input if he is creating custom courses? Will he be passing you course titles or something else?

Comment: Create your List of course based on the course title and return the Course list

Answer (score 0):

Create a Parent Class Course with Math and Science as Child classes.